# What is the "+01:00" in "2006-04-03 08:00:00+01:00" datetime timestamp object?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, timezone

I printed out a `<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>` `time` variable, and it displays as

```
2006-04-03 08:00:00+01:00
```

I am wondering what is the `+01:00` at the end? Seems this is related to daylight savings?

When I did

```
print(time.timestamp())
```

I am seeing

```
1144047600.0
```

which is off by 3600 (an hour).

Comment: No, that's the timezone.  That's Europe/London, which is one hour ahead of UTC.

Comment: ISO 8601 [Time offsets from UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC).

Comment: @TimRoberts -- or Atlantic/Canary or Africa/Luanda or ... see the full list in the answer below.

Comment: BTW 1144047600 is the correct Unix timestanp for the date-time you’ve got.

Comment: Perhaps a better link: [UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset)

Answer (score 3):

`+01:00` specifies an [offset from UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC). Positive means ahead of UTC, so 8 am +01:00 would be 7 am UTC. Negative means behind UTC, so 8 am -01:00 would be 9 am UTC.

In that context, "timezone" is often mentioned. However it is important to note that many time zones in a geographical sense / as you can find them in the [IANA database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) can share the same UTC offset at a given point in time.

Also, a UTC offset alone doesn't tell you anything about DST. For that you need to know the timezone. The combination of date/time, timezone and the [rules](https://github.com/eggert/tz) associated with that timezone allow you to determine if DST is active or not.

For your example date try the following:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import zoneinfo

dt = datetime.fromisoformat("2006-04-03")

# let's assume a time zone and see if DST is active:
dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo("Europe/London"))
print(dt, dt.dst())
# 2006-04-03 00:00:00+01:00 1:00:00
#--> so yes, DST is active, offset of one hour

# let's see which time zones share UTC+1 on that date:
for z in zoneinfo.available_timezones():
    if dt.replace(tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(z)).strftime("%z") == "+0100":
        print(z)
```

```
>>>      
Europe/Guernsey
Europe/Jersey
GB
Africa/Ndjamena
GB-Eire
Europe/London
Europe/Belfast
Eire
Europe/Dublin
Africa/Algiers
Atlantic/Canary
Atlantic/Faroe
Europe/Lisbon
Atlantic/Faeroe
Etc/GMT-1
Africa/Bangui
Africa/Porto-Novo
Africa/Libreville
Africa/Malabo
Africa/Kinshasa
Africa/Lagos
Africa/Luanda
Atlantic/Madeira
Africa/Windhoek
Europe/Isle_of_Man
Africa/Niamey
Portugal
WET
Africa/Douala
Africa/Brazzaville
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is the "+01:00" in "2006-04-03 08:00:00+01:00" ...?

This is the timezone [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) in the format specified by [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC) standard. In this example, it tells that `2006-04-03 08:00:00+01:00` is offset by one hour from [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) i.e. the equivalent date-time at UTC will be `2006-04-03T07:00Z` where `Z` is the abbreviation for `Zulu` and represents the timezone offset of `00:00`.

As you can see, the calculation is simple: To get the UTC date-time from a date-time with a different offset, subtract the excess offset or add the less offset, as applicable.

My area of expertise is Java and therefore, I am presenting a demo using Java language.

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX");

        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2006-04-03 08:00:00+01:00", parser);
        System.out.println(odt);
        System.out.println(odt.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));

        odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2006-04-03 08:00:00-01:00", parser);
        System.out.println(odt);
        System.out.println(odt.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2006-04-03T08:00+01:00
2006-04-03T07:00Z
2006-04-03T08:00-01:00
2006-04-03T09:00Z
```

<kbd>[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/I3FIto)</kbd>

You may be interested to know the difference between timezone and timezone offset. A timezone ID is typically specified as Region/City e.g. `America/New_York`, `Europe/London` etc. You can check the tz database [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). A timezone can have one or more timezone offsets e.g. `Asia/Kolkata` has a single timezone offset of `+05:30`. In comparison `Europe/London` has two timezone offsets: `+01:00` in summer while `+00:00` in winter as per its [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) schedules. Because of this reason, an object representing a date-time with timezone is designed to adjust its timezone offset automatically. On the other hand, an object representing a date-time with timezone offset contains a fixed offset value. The following demo shows how a `ZonedDateTime` in Java automatically adjusts its offset.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");

        ZonedDateTime zdtSummer = LocalDate.of(2022, 5, 20).atStartOfDay(zoneId);
        System.out.println(zdtSummer);

        ZonedDateTime zdtWinter = LocalDate.of(2022, 11, 20).atStartOfDay(zoneId);
        System.out.println(zdtWinter);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-05-20T00:00+01:00[Europe/London]
2022-11-20T00:00Z[Europe/London]
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: I find the use of the word "timezone" in the first sentence to be confusing. No time zone is involved in that string input.